# Jquery datatable search and show entries are to the left of my table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have created a Jquery Datatable in my application.  When it renders, the search and show entries fields are to the left of my table, like this:

[image]

My code is here:

```
@model IEnumerable<Exemptions.ViewModels.ViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()



@using (Html.BeginForm(new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    if (ViewBag.Role == "Officer")
    {
        <div><h1>Please select a Report to view from the Reports Menu</h1></div>
    }
    else if (ViewBag.Role == "PermitAdmin" || ViewBag.Role == "Employee")
    {
        <table class="table" id="id" style="width:75%" border="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">
                    <h3>*Search for an Exemption or Create a new Exemption from this page:* </h3>
                    <p class="input-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">
                            <input type="button" value="Create New Owner" class="btn btn-md btn-default " onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Owners")'" />
                        </label>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="table" id="myTable" style="width:75%" border="1" align="center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="20%">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Land Owner ID", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                    </th>
                    <th width="20%">
                        @Html.ActionLink("First Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.FNameLSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                    </th>
                    <th width="20%">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LNameLSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                    </th>
                    <th width="30%">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    if (ViewBag.Role == "PermitAdmin")
                    {
                        <tr class="@(item.Owner.RecordDeleted ? "danger" : string.Empty) ">
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Owner.LandOwnerID)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Owner.FNameL)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Owner.LNameL)
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                                @if (item.Owner.RecordDeleted == false)
                                {
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit Landowner", "Edit", new { id = item.Owner.LandOwnerID }) <span> | </span>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit Exemption", "Index", "Permits", new { id = item.Owner.LandOwnerID }, null)
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <div>Record Deleted</div>
                                }
                                @if (ViewBag.Role == "PermitAdmin" && item.Owner.RecordDeleted == false)
                                {<span> | </span>@Html.ActionLink("Delete Landowner", "Delete", "Owners", new { id = item.Owner.LandOwnerID }, null)}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Owner.LandOwnerID)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Owner.FNameL)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Owner.LNameL)
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit Landowner", "Edit", new { id = item.Owner.LandOwnerID }) <span> | </span>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit Exemption", "Index", "Permits", new { id = item.Owner.LandOwnerID }, null)

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

    }
    else if (ViewBag.Role == "None")
    {
        <div>
            <h2>
                Error! You must be a member of the Officer, Employee, or PermitAdmin groups to view this data!<br />
                <br />Please contact <contact info> to be added to the appropriate group!
            </h2>
        </div>
    }
    else if (ViewBag.Role == "NoUserFound")
    {
        <div>
            <h2>
                Error! We could not find your record in our system!<br />
                <br />Please contact <contact info> to create your account!
            </h2>
            <p><img src="~/Content/images/wildhog.jpeg" /></p>
        </div>
    }

}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Edit to add:  I would like the search box and show entries fields to be above my table.

What do I need to do to fix this?  Google has not been helpful at all.  :-(

Apparently I can't post this question because there is too much code compared to the text of my message, so I apologize ahead of time for this:

Ignore this; it's to get past the filter.

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

Regards,
Carthax

Comment: What is your expectation? Do you want the search and show entries right at the top of the table or where?

Comment: @VajidKagdi, I would like it to appear at the top of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use below configuration for moving the search box to bottom right:

```
$('table').DataTable({ "dom": '<"top"i>flrtp<"clear">' });
```

PS: "bottom"flp means filtering, length change and pagination will be at the bottom.

```
l - Length changing
f - Filtering input
t - The Table!
i - Information
p - Pagination
r - pRocessing
< and > - div elements
<"#id" and > - div with an id
<"class" and > - div with a class
<"#id.class" and > - div with an id and class
```

Reference: https://www.ihbc.org.uk/consultationsdb_new/examples/basic_init/dom.html